# How can I generate and use a random number until the end of a process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I need to generate a random number via a function, return it to another function and then run that second function multiple times with the same random number I got in the first place.
But the random number generator makes a new one whenever my function summons it for the random number. (Python3.7)

```
import random
from sys import exit

def rand():
    n = random.randint(1, 1001)
    return n

n = rand()

def isdigit(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def guess():
    g = input("> ")

    if isdigit(g):
        return int(g)

    elif not isdigit(g):
        print("\tPlease enter a number.")
        guess()


def islower():
    print("\tThe number is GREATER than that!")
    process()

def ishigher():
    print("\tThe number is SMALLER than that!")
    process()

def gotit():
    print(f"\tCongratulations! You got it! The number was {n}.")

    print("\tPlay another hand? y/n")
    again = input("> ")
    if again == "y":
        newgame()
    elif again == "n":
        print("\tHave fun!")
        exit(0)


def process():

    g = guess()

    if g > n:
        ishigher()

    elif g < n:
        islower()

    elif g == n:
        gotit()

def newgame():
    print("\tI have chosen my number. Start!")
    process()


newgame()
```

Comment: Post some code? Sounds like you just made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Sounds like you need to remove the generation of random number just above the loop where you run your second function multiple times.

Comment: How do you know that `n` is changing every-time you call `process`? Have you tried putting `print(n)` inside? Also, this is not a clear way to write code. I would suggest using [`if __name__ == __main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/1011724). You should set the value for `n` inside `newgame()`, not just in the wild like you have. And then pass the value around i.e. `process()` should take `n` as an argument. If you don't want to pass it around then make an object and set `n` as a state variable or if you want to stick with your functional pattern, create `process` as a closure.

Comment: I think `n` should change every time the game restarted, but it does not change at all. When you enter `y` to play again, the random number is still the same one before which makes no sense. To change it, user must close the game and re run the program.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give you an answer without a simple example of code, but the first thing I think of is : can't you store the result of the random generator in a variable and use this variable as an input of your second function ? Something like :

```py
def get_a_random_number():
   # Whatever method you use to generate your random number
   return random_number

def your_other_function(a_random_number):
  # Do what you need with the random number

my_random_number = get_a_random_number()

# Repeatedly use your other function
your_other_function(my_random_number)
your_other_function(my_random_number)
your_other_function(my_random_number)
your_other_function(my_random_number)
...
```

Comment: Well, technically what you have written would make no difference than calling a random generator multiple times. Whenever your_other_function calls my_random_number it goes to get_a_random_number then that calls for another random number with the help of random module. You just made a train.

Comment: ```my_random_number``` is a variable, not a callable, and it is not evaluated each time it is used by ```your_other_function()```

Comment: You're right. I was in mistake.

Comment: But how can I update this random number (assign a new one to that variable) after I have done a series of code?

Comment: Just call `my_random_number = get_a_random_number()` again

Answer (score 0):

If you initialized the two functions just once

```
rand_number = random_generator()
other_func(rand_number)
```

Python script will return a new value each time when it ran. So What you can do is call the `other_func` multiple time and pass the variable or loop the seond function multiple times.

```
for _ in range(x):
    other_func(rand_number)
```